Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice 3rd edition graphics: why passing a callback function to Window::timer_wait gets unexpected results?
Section 14.6 (Simple animation) in Stroustrup's "Programming Principles and Practice using C++" third edition uses his PPP graphics library, which in turn makes use of QT. I am trying to understand what is involved.
The following program works as intended: initially it displays two black circles. After 2 seconds the first circle changes color to red. After four more seconds the second circle changes color to blue.
Stroustrup writes: "You can also add an action ("callback") as an argument. That action is invoked after the delay". So I experimented by replacing the indicated lines of code with code that does this. I expected the output to be exactly the same, but it is not. At two seconds nothing happens, but at four seconds both circles change color at the same time.
#include "PPP/Simple_window.h"
#include "PPP/Graph.h"

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/[])
{
    using namespace Graph_lib;
    Application app;

    // Window initially displays 2 black circles
    Simple_window w {Point{0,0}, 600, 400, "Callback problem"};
    Circle c1{{175, 200}, 100};
    Circle c2{{425, 200}, 100};
    c1.set_fill_color(Color::black);
    c2.set_fill_color(Color::black);
    w.attach(c1);
    w.attach(c2);

    // Code to be replaced:
    w.timer_wait(2000);    //2000 milliseconds
    c1.set_fill_color(Color::red);
    w.timer_wait(4000);
    c2.set_fill_color(Color::blue);
    //////////////////////////////

    // // I expected this code to have the same result:
    // w.timer_wait(2000, [&]{c1.set_fill_color(Color::red);});
    // w.timer_wait(4000, [&]{c2.set_fill_color(Color::blue);});
    // //////////////////////////////////////////////

    w.wait_for_button();
 }

Why is the output not the same? Is there something I can do to use the callback method successfully?
Here is the code for timer_wait:
void WindowPrivate::timer_wait(int milliseconds, std::function<void()> cb)
{
    if (!accept_waits)
        return;
    auto conn = std::make_shared<QMetaObject::Connection>();
    *conn = QObject::connect(&user_timer, &QTimer::timeout,
                     [conn, func = std::move(cb)] {
        QObject::disconnect(*conn);
        func();
    });
    user_timer.start(milliseconds);
}


Please post a [mcve] with Simple_window definition. The second w.timer_wait() likely replaces the first one.

The callback argument implies that it will be called when the given time has passed, without blocking the code execution, which is exactly what the timer_wait() with the timeout only does. UI toolkits use event loops that require that control is always returned to them as soon as possible in order to process events, including UI updates (redraws): with timer_wait(2000) you're preventing that, and all will be finally executed once the event loop can be properly processed, which is what wait_for_button() probably does. Also, in your code the final result will be at 6 seconds, not 4.

My stopwatch does say 4 seconds.

@musicamante answers should go to the answer section

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I can't provide an appropriate answer until a proper MRE is provided.

@musicamante I was hoping for help from someone who is familiar with Stroustrup's PPP3 support, perhaps as a teacher or student. The Simple_window definition involves several levels  on top of the QT code, and I admit that I am not able to give an MRE more satisfactory than what I have already posted.

@freeze It's strange that it says 4 seconds, since you have 2000+4000ms "sleep", unless timer_wait internally keeps track of previous intervals, which seems an odd choice, but not impossible (we'd have to see how it's actually implemented, you should at least provide the code related to that function). That said, the point remains: I can't write an appropriate answer for this specific case, but considering the behavior we can probably refer you many related posts here on SO (probably starting with this, but I'll leave it to more C++ experienced »

@freeze » people to find more appropriate duplicates); as said, if timer_wait with the interval argument alone is blocking (and I suppose it is), it prevents the event loop to properly process events, and therefore redrawing the UI with the new changes: by default graphical changes schedule an update. In standard Qt, you can partially work around that by using QCoreApplication::processEvents(), but that's not always acceptable; other alternatives are based on QTimer, which is what the timer_wait with callback seems to do.

@musicamante Thank you for your comments. I have edited my post to include the implementation code for the function timer_wait.

the code is still incomplete. Though user_timer.start(milliseconds); looks very much like Simple_window has a single timer that waits only for the time passed on the last call.

@freeze That's the function that accepts a callback. There should be an override for that function that only accepts the timeout, which is the one causing your "issue". Check again, and also verify the implementation of the classes from which Simple_window inherits.

I managed to find the code online: https://github.com/villevoutilainen/ProgrammingPrinciplesAndPracticeUsingQt/blob/main/Window.cpp (linked in the (official site)[https://www.stroustrup.com/PPP3.html]). The blocking is caused by the nested_loop QEventLoop, which in theory should allow queued events to be processed, but it's also known that nested loops sometimes have unexpected behavior. set_fill_color() seems to call redraw() which should cause a repaint on the parent widget, as it's using QWidget repaint(). Try to call redraw() of c1 right after set_fill_color().

@musicamante I fully admit that this discussion is beyond my current abilities. My original question was posed in order to see if I was using the PPP graphics library incorrectly. From what I understand here, it would seem that the library itself does not accomplish what it purports to do. In particular, timer_wait, when called with a function as an argument does not actually wait for the given time (presumably because of unexpected behavior of nested loops).

@musicamante However, I will point out that nested_loop.quit() only occurs in the timer_wait override that does NOT take a function as argument. My issue is with the override that does.

@freeze Ok, now I get it: we simply misunderstood ourselves. Your issue is with the commented code, which shows the change of the two circles simultaneously. I'll answer shortly.

@musicamante Thank you for your excellent answer. It will take me some time to digest it. In the meantime I have found a work around that seems to work.

The issue is caused by the fact that WindowPrivate always uses the same QTimer object; see GUI_Private.h:
    QTimer user_timer{&nested_loop};

When calling multiple timer_wait(timeout, callback) functions sequentially, they actually call the timer's start(msec):

Starts or restarts the timer with a timeout interval of msec milliseconds.
If the timer is already running, it will be stopped and restarted.

The result is that the second time timer_wait(timeout, callback) is called, the timer is immediately reset and restarted with the new timeout.
This is obviously not satisfactory for general usage, but it's also understandable due to the simple nature and purpose of the PPP library: it's a basic library intended for educational purposes, therefore it has somehow limited capabilities. I don't know if the implementation in the previous versions of the library (before switching to Qt) had a different result, but maybe it should be worth writing to Stroustrups and let him know about this issue, which should at least be documented, if not fixed in some way.
In a real program, you would probably use two distinct timers, one for each callback.
I believe it doesn't make a lot of sense to try and fix the PPP implementation, but you could use the existing Qt capabilities for this case.
Specifically, you can use the QTimer::singleShot() static functions, which can also be used with lambdas:
#include <QTimer>

...

    QTimer::singleShot(2000, [&]{c1.set_fill_color(Color::red);});
    QTimer::singleShot(4000, [&]{c2.set_fill_color(Color::blue);});

Be aware of an important fact: the above usage of QTimer expects that whatever is accessed within the functor still exists when it's finally called.
A more appropriate usage of the singleShot static functions uses the context of the target (a QObject) and automatically disconnects the function whenever it's destroyed.
Alternatively, an actual QTimer object can be constructed with a parent (which could be the "sender" or the "receiver", depending on the situation), and then connect its timeout with the related function.
